# Smalltalk referring to classes that are not yet defined

Tags: smalltalk

I want to be able to write code like this:

```
MyObject subclass: #A instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'CAT1'.
A subclass: #B instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'CAT1'.
```

without running each line seperately.

When I try to do this I get an error saying that `A` isn't declared, even if it will be declared by the time the second line will be reached.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deferred lookups of classes, you have to look up the class in the dictionary of globals, called `Smalltalk` (try to inspect and browse it). You can use accessors like `classNamed:` or `at:` to look up a name that might not be defined yet when the whole expression that you want to evaluate is compiled.

```
MyObject subclass: #A instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'CAT1'.
(Smalltalk classNamed: #A) subclass: #B instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'CAT1'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some dialects support the `asClass` message on `Symbol`, allowing you to do:

```
MyObject subclass: #A instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'CAT1'.
#A asClasss subclass: #B instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' poolDictionaries: '' category: 'CAT1
```